# Resolve LaTeX Error: Cannot determine size of graphic X (no BoundingBox)

Tags: pstricks, overleaf, arxiv

I am using Overleaf and must use LaTeX compiler. This is because I use `pst-poker` which only works with LaTeX or XeLaTeX and want to submit to arXiv which does not accepts XeLaTeX.)

I have several images in formats JPG and PNG.  Compiling the paper with XeLaTeX produces no errors, however when switching to the LaTeX compiler each image produces this "No Bounding Box" error.

I saw I need to determine the bounding box this way:

```
\includegraphics[width=0.8\linewdith,bb=0 0 100 100]{figurefile}
```

However it does not work, the PDF it produces contains only the 2 pages before the first image appears.

> Problem:
>
> LaTeX-Compiler can’t determine the graphic-size, because there is no
>   such information in the graphics-file.
>
> Error messages like: “Cannot determine size of graphic  (no
>   BoundingBox)”

I have tried:

1. Use a graphic file format, which saves picture-size information, e.g. EPS

   - `.eps` is too large, exceeds the size limit of arXiv
2. Use the PdfLaTeX compiler instead of the LaTeX compiler

   - Can't use PdfLaTeX since it is not compatible with `pst-poker`.
3. Specify the picture size manually: `\includegraphics[scale=0.75, natwidth=640, natheight=480]{picture.jpg}`

   - Does not work, I get a white box, no image.

[On a similar question](http://!%20LaTeX%20Error:%20Cannot%20determine%20size%20of%20graphic%20in%E2%80%A6pdf%20or%20png%20(no%20BoundingBox)) someone answered that LaTeX does not support anything other than EPS. -- Is that right?

**EDIT:** 
I need the `pst-poker` package to draw cards symbols as the paper is about a card game.

[image]

Comment: i have add \usepackage[dvipdfmx]{graphicx}, now I can't see the images, just white boxes where they need to be placed.

Comment: Can you provide the MWE and the image itself?

Comment: sorry, but what is MWE?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_working_example

Comment: @campa that is probably bad advice in this case as the OP is using latex+dvips to get postscript handling and using dvipdfmx cuts out the postscript and goes straight to pdf.

Comment: use _always_ `xelatex`!

Comment: you may be able to use the pst-pdf package to use pstricks with pdflatex, but as you have provided no testfile, I can't say whether the subset of pstricks that works in this way is enough for your needs.

Comment: I am working with XeLatex however I try to make it arXiv compatible, and arXiv do not acept XeLatex.  pdfLatex is not compatible with the pst-poker package I use.

Comment: @user187802 if you are going to give that advice, you need to explain to the user how to submit to arxiv when the arxiv faq https://arxiv.org/help/faq/mistakes explicitly says that xelatex is not supported.

Comment: What exactly do you need from pst-poker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with `pdflatex --shell-escape file`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{pst-poker}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}\crdAs\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]